# Eliminate duplicate lines and write into a file

Tags: python, file, awk, grep, python-re

file1.txt has below lines:

```
[SUM]   0.00-34.53  sec  2.11 GBytes   524 Mbits/sec                  sender    
[SUM]   0.00-34.53  sec  2.11 GBytes   524 Mbits/sec                  sender    
[SUM]   0.00-34.62  sec  2.36 GBytes   586 Mbits/sec                  sender    
[SUM]   0.00-34.62  sec  2.36 GBytes   586 Mbits/sec                  sender 
[SUM]   0.00-34.75  sec  2.39 GBytes   591 Mbits/sec                  receiver  
[SUM]   0.00-34.75  sec  2.39 GBytes   591 Mbits/sec                  receiver  
[0]   0.00-34.53  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  receiver 
[0]   0.00-34.75  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
```

printing the lines that starts with [SUM] and ends with sender and receiver into another text file-file2.txt.

Below is the Code :

```
with open(r"C:\Users\file1.txt", 'r') as f:

 contents = f.read()
 s=contents

def my_function1():

 regex = "^\s*\[SUM\]\s*[0-9\-\.]+\s+sec(?!\s+0\.00 Bytes).*sender.*"   
 items=re.findall(regex,s,re.MULTILINE)
 for y in items:
   file=open('file2.txt', "a")
   file.write(str(y))
   file.write("\n")
   file.close()


def my_function2():

 regex = "^\s*\[SUM\]\s*[0-9\-\.]+\s+sec(?!\s+0\.00 Bytes).*receiver.*"   
 items=re.findall(regex,s,re.MULTILINE)
 for y in items:
   file=open('file2.txt', "a")
   file.write(str(y))
   file.write("\n")
   file.close()
   #print(y)

my_function1()

my_function2()
```

which writes the output in file2.txt as :

```
[SUM]   0.00-34.53  sec  2.11 GBytes   524 Mbits/sec                  sender    
[SUM]   0.00-34.53  sec  2.11 GBytes   524 Mbits/sec                  sender    
[SUM]   0.00-34.62  sec  2.36 GBytes   586 Mbits/sec                  sender    
[SUM]   0.00-34.62  sec  2.36 GBytes   586 Mbits/sec                  sender
[SUM]   0.00-34.62  sec  2.36 GBytes   586 Mbits/sec                  sender 
[SUM]   0.00-34.75  sec  2.39 GBytes   591 Mbits/sec                  receiver  
[SUM]   0.00-34.75  sec  2.39 GBytes   591 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

Expected : print only one occurence

```
[SUM]   0.00-34.53  sec  2.11 GBytes   524 Mbits/sec                  sender
[SUM]   0.00-34.62  sec  2.36 GBytes   586 Mbits/sec                  sender
[SUM]   0.00-34.75  sec  2.39 GBytes   591 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

Comment: You could store the matching lines in a set and check if a new line is already present in the set. If not, add it and write it to file.

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk '/^\[SUM]/ && !seen[$0]++' file
[SUM]   0.00-34.53  sec  2.11 GBytes   524 Mbits/sec                  sender
[SUM]   0.00-34.62  sec  2.36 GBytes   586 Mbits/sec                  sender
[SUM]   0.00-34.62  sec  2.36 GBytes   586 Mbits/sec                  sender
[SUM]   0.00-34.75  sec  2.39 GBytes   591 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

As you can see you don't need as complicated a regexp as you thought given your posted sample input but if you did then maybe something like this is what you're looking for (uses GNU awk for `\s`, with other awks use `[[:space:]]`):

```
$ awk '/^\s*\[SUM]\s*[0-9.-]+\s+sec\s.*(sender|receiver)/ && !seen[$0]++' file
[SUM]   0.00-34.53  sec  2.11 GBytes   524 Mbits/sec                  sender
[SUM]   0.00-34.62  sec  2.36 GBytes   586 Mbits/sec                  sender
[SUM]   0.00-34.62  sec  2.36 GBytes   586 Mbits/sec                  sender
[SUM]   0.00-34.75  sec  2.39 GBytes   591 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

Comment: Although `awk` a great tool for this, it's not a `python` solution as tagged in the question.

Comment: @RoadRunner The OP tagged python and grep so they're apparently not set on any one tool, just tagging what tools they might be familiar with, and we frequently see questions tagged with grep that are solved by awk (or sed or some other tool).

Comment: I removed the grep tag because the question had nothing to do with grep.

Comment: Seems like the `grep` tag was removed from an edit.

Comment: It wasn't the OP who removed it so I put it back as it tells us the OP isn't focused on just python.

Comment: Fair, OP should have stated that explicitly, not my fault

Comment: @EdMorton this is the actual regex : regex = "^\s*[SUM]\s*[0-9\-\.]+\s+sec(?!\s+0\.00 Bytes).*sender.*" How to use awk here

Comment: With GNU awk (which supports \s) just change `/^one.*apple$/` to `/^\s*[SUM]\s*[0-9\-\.]+\s+sec(?!\s+0\.00 Bytes).*sender.*/`. With other awks do the same but change every `\s` to `[[:space:]]`. Oh, also change `[0-9\-\.]` to `[0-9.-]` everywhere as what you have right now is not POSIX compliant. If that doesn't work for you then post some more realistic sample input/output such that a tool would require that regexp to work so we can help you solve the problem.

Comment: @aishwaryaramesh from your sample input/output, you don't need such a complicated regexp anyway. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the re module here, nor have to load everything in memory:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\file1.txt", 'r') as f, open('file2.txt', "w") as file:
    seen = set()     # use a set to only keep distinct lines
    for line in f:   # iterate the input file
        lr = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith('one') and lr.endswith('apple'):
            if lr not in seen:
                seen.add(lr)
                _ = file.write(line)
```

---

If the search if actually more complex and requires the `re` module, I would still stick to processing one line at a time and compile the regex outside of the loop:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\file1.txt", 'r') as f, open('file2.txt', "w") as file:
    seen = set()     # use a set to only keep distinct lines
    rx = re.compile(pattern)
    for line in f:   # iterate the input file
        lr = line.rstrip()
        if rx.match(lr):
            if lr not in seen:
                seen.add(lr)
                _ = file.write(line)
```

---

If you need to search against 2 patterns and ensure that matches for the first one are written before matches for the second ones, you could use:

```
patterns = ["^\s*\[SUM\]\s*[0-9\-\.]+\s+sec(?!\s+0\.00 Bytes).*sender.*",
            "^\s*\[SUM\]\s*[0-9\-\.]+\s+sec(?!\s+0\.00 Bytes).*receiver.*"]
rxs = [re.compile(pattern) for pattern in patterns]

with open(r"C:\Users\file1.txt", 'r') as f:
    data = [[], []]
    seen = set()     # use a set to only keep distinct lines
    for line in f:   # iterate the input file
        lr = line.rstrip()
        for i, rx in enumerate(rxs):
            if rx.match(lr):
                if lr not in seen:
                    seen.add(lr)
                    data[i].append(line)
with open('file2.txt', "w") as file:
    for lst in data:
        for line in lst:
            _ = file.write(line)
    print(file.getvalue())
```

It gives the expected:

```
[SUM]   0.00-34.53  sec  2.11 GBytes   524 Mbits/sec                  sender    
[SUM]   0.00-34.62  sec  2.36 GBytes   586 Mbits/sec                  sender    
[SUM]   0.00-34.75  sec  2.39 GBytes   591 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

Comment: this is the actual regex : regex = "^\s*\[SUM\]\s*[0-9\-\.]+\s+sec(?!\s+0\.00 Bytes).*sender.*"   
 items=re.findall(regex,s,re.MULTILINE) in this case i cannot use :if line.startswith('one') and lr.endswith('apple'): kindly look into this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a unique list, just add:
`list(set(items))`
before writing to the file

Comment: This requires loading whole source file which is pretty bad idea + it is absolutely not needed